# Databases missing after exporting server and rebuilding master DB

Tags: sql-server, recovery

We had a server running Microsoft SQL Server 2014 databases on Hyper-V. I exported it (with `C:` and `D:` drives) and opened on other machine.

I could not start the `MSSQLSERVER` service because it said the *master* db needed to be rebuilt.

I've rebuilt the *master* db, but now the databases are empty, I cannot see databases except *master*, *model*, *msdb*, and *tempdb*.

I have all databases (mdf and ldf files) in this folder `D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`. How to restore them and not lose all functionality?

Comment: Did you migrate and attach the volume (VHD) that represents the D drive of the VM as well?

Comment: Yes I did. C and D drives

Answer (score 2):

> I have all Databases (mdf and ldf files) in this folder D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA how to restore them and not lose all functionality?

When you rebuild master, it loses track of where the user databases are.  You just need to [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=To%20Attach%20a%20Database.%201%20In%20SQL%20Server,Files%20dialog%20box%2C%20select%20the%20disk%20...%20) them, and recreate the logins for any [orphaned users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20Identify%20orphaned%20users%20in%20those%20environments%20with,are%20user%20SID%27s%20in%20the%20user...%20More%20).

And also consider linked servers, scheduled jobs and everything else which is stored outside the user databases and was scratched by the rebuild.

Comment: The thing is, that admin credentials cannot contact domain controller and let me into SQL server. It is maybe off-topic. And other credentials have no rights to attach or recreate logins. My brain just thinks only to clone DC. Or are there no such brutal ways?

Comment: If you're logged on as a local administrator and can't connect to SQL Server as a sysadmin, follow the procedure here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15.  If you can't contact the domain controller to authenticate, then that's a separate issue, but you can fix the SQL Server using a local admin account.

Comment: Do you have enough privileges to use SQLCMD? https://support.atandra.com/article/70-command-line-to-attach-sql-server-database. If privileges are the problem you have to fix that first: contact your sysadmin.

Comment: You said "recreate the logins for orphaned users"
The link "orphaned users" said "execute the following statement in the user database:" - what is user database? Where to execute this query?